# Is it possible to get GPS location from Android Wear SDK?

Tags: android, wear-os

I have connected my `Samsung GEAR Live`  to my Android device through `bluetooth`. I have active internet connection & `GPS` enabled on my Android device.

Now, I am trying to get the GPS location from `Wearable App`.

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Activity.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            // getting GPS status
            boolean isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            // getting network status
            boolean isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            if (isGPSEnabled == false && isNetworkEnabled == false) {
                location = null;
            } else if (isGPSEnabled) {
                location = locationManager
                        .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            }
            if (isNetworkEnabled && location == null) {
                location = locationManager
                        .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            }
```

But, `isGPSEnabled` and `isNetworkEnabled` both are returning false.

What could be the reason? How to get the location from `Wearable App` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Android Wear is a normal Android device. These API returns false because your Android Wear device doesn't have GPS or network connection.

1. You can implement your own "GPS provider" that sends gps position obtained by a phone to your to Wearable app.
2. You can use Google Play services Location API to obtain GPS position because they have made it work automatically on Wear. Here is a post on Google+ that confirms this: https://plus.google.com/+PaulGoldstein/posts/FhkgND7USgx

To implements Google Play services please follow these tutorials:
**Retrieving the Current Location:**
https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html
**Receiving Location Updates:**
https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html
Please notice that it should work with any of Location API so you can also use APIs like `ActivityRecognitionApi`, `GeofencingApi` etc.
https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/package-summary.html

Comment: Will this return the location if we connect to Android Device via Bluetooth? In GoogleGlass it was working fine. But, for Android wear its not working.

Comment: AFAIK: Google Glass has both GPS and internet connection "tethered" from phone by default. Android Wear handles these differently and you don't have direct access of these two services. But they have made GPS (from phone) available on your Android Wear by using Google Play Services Location API to make it easier and avoid everyone to implement it on your own (as in approach 1.)

Comment: Can you please the sample snippet to get the current location using GPS? I am not able to get that from the reference links which you have posted.

Comment: There are many lines of "bolierplate" code to implement in order to setup the Location API - you have to check for GP services, connect to them etc. Please take a look at this tutorial: https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html. I don't think that copying&pasting all of these code makes much sense here. There are also some helpful information included (for better code understanding etc.) so it'd be nice to look at it yourself:) In the end the location can be accessed as shown here: https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html#GetLocation

Comment: How about sending SMS from the wearable app that is tethered to Android Mobile Device using bluetooth?

Comment: AFAIK Android Wear cannot use any of phone functionality directly... The only way to communicate with phone is to use Google Play Services - mainly by Wearable APIS: MessageApi, DataApi; but also non-wearable APIs that are made to work between devices - like mentioned Location API (there is no information from Google which other APIs will work that way)

Comment: Sony SmartWatch3 has a built in GPS. The standard AVD emulator does not seem to support local GPS. For example: locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER); Why?

Comment: Maybe it just doesn't have GPS enabled? I don't know, but you you should use Google Play Services to access GPS anyway instead of manually accessing location API. Please see the following tutorial: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/wear-location-detection.html. Hope it will help:)