# Retrieving GPS location from a mobile device using Google Play Services from the Wear device

Tags: android, gps, google-play-services, wear-os

I have a fullscreen Android Wear application that needs to access location data periodically. I've read in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24849271/924313) that the correct way to do it would be to connect to Google Play Services, which are supposed to transparently provide location data from the phone.

I followed [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html), and set up a `FragmentActivity` that overrides the required methods. It gets connected to Google Play Services, but `mLocationClient.getLastLocation()` is constantly returning `null`.

Is there something else that is needed for the device to actually get the correct last location? So far I haven't even touched the mobile application - is there something I need to configure there as well? (I added the fine location permissions on both applications).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the location data can only be returned from a device that is able to find the location. All the Android Wear devices at the moment are not able to do it.

That means, that you'll have to get the location in the phone app on a background service and send it to the wear device.

in short:

- wear device starts full screen application and connect to Google Play Services for wear communication
- phone receives broadcast receiver from wear and starts service
- phone service connects to Google Play Services for location and for wear device connection.
- phone service receives location
- phone service sends location to wear device
- wear device receives data with location

Comment: I think your answer might be outdated, from the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24849271/924313) I've linked: *You can use Google Play services Location API to obtain GPS position because they have made it work automatically on Wear. Here is a post on Google+ that confirms this: https://plus.google.com/+PaulGoldstein/posts/FhkgND7USgx.*

Comment: I'm really sorry but from this post and all the comments i saw nothing confirming it. It's pretty much people asking and wanting the same you want, but nothing confirms that you can do automatically thought wear. Maybe in the future, that would be great, but that's not how it's working now (August-2014). Plus, I've been on a wear workshop with some Google guys,  n no, not yet.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that the Fused Location API (https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html) does indeed return GPS coords on the Android Wear device itself - so it IS certainly possible.

I have had less success in geolocating that data and turning it into something more usable in the UI. I'd like to hear if someone has had success doing this without resorting to message passing back and forth between watch and phone.

Comment: I'll be able to check this in a week, then I'll confirm you. But I did solve this via message passing because that just worked.